# iOS UITableview delete row with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I saw a lot of questions about it but didn't found a solution to my problem.

I have a tableview with custom cell. In each cell I have a timer. When the time is out, I send a message to delete the row (it's not the only place where I use the reception of the message).

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)theTableView{
    return 1;
}

- (void) timesup:(NSNotification *)notification{
    Data *data = notification.userInfo[@"data"];
    NSUInteger index = [datas indexOfObject:data];
    NSArray *deleteIndexPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                 [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0],
                                 nil];
    [datas removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(datas.count > 0){
        return datas.count;
    }

    // Display a message when the table is empty
    UILabel *messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];

    messageLabel.text = @"No data, pull to refresh";
    messageLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    messageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [messageLabel sizeToFit];

    self.tableView.backgroundView = messageLabel;
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    return 0;
}
```

An I got this error (depending of how many datas I have when playing with the app) :

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (6), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

The error occurs when I have a lot of datas time out.

NB : if I don't use "deleteRowsAtIndexPaths", only delete from datas and reloadTable it works perfectly

Comment: Try using an async serial que to dispath the deletion logic (within your notification method). This way the deletions will be serialized in FIFO order. or better check the code that I have given below.

Comment: any piece of code to show (started iOS dev one week ago :D)

Comment: It is advised to use `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`. Also, make sure number of rows/sections is equal to the number of items in your data source array, after deletion.

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I'd solved the similar issue which you've written in your N.B. with the same way you suggested. What I believe is this problem occurs when table datasource got confused. To overcome this situation a might be possible solution to implement correct flow for the deletion of rows.

BOOL isDeleteInProgress;

Steps:

- when your timer event fires (call) set isDeleteInProgress to YES.
- if its call again because of another timer check if isDeleteInProgress to NO then only set to YES
- now write below code to delete the rows

  [self.tableView beginUpdates];

  [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

  [self.tableView endUpdates];
- once row delete successfully set isDeleteInProgress to NO.

This will prevent continuos call for the deletion and may prevent you from this (unsolved) exception.

I've read your comment (*any piece of code to show (started iOS dev one week ago :D)*) so do I add a pseudo code that may help you.

```
- (void)timerEventFire:(NSTimer*)timer {
    if(!isDeleteInProgress) {
        //write code to delete the rows
        //invalidate timer
        //isDeleteInProgress = NO;
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: looks to be a good workaround but how do you manage undeleted rows because delete was already in progress ?

Comment: @Titmael, We should not worry for *undeleted rows* this will manage by datasource it self.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. Add a variable to your class interface:
`dispatch_queue_t _deleteQeue;`

2. In your `viewDidLoad` initialize the qeue:
 `_deleteQeue = dispatch_queue_create("com.delte.qeue", NULL);` 
3. Finally change the implementation of your method to look like this:

```
dispatch_sync(_deleteQeue, ^{
    //your deletion code that you have implemented. Deletion from datasource array
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //cell delete code here. The table animation code. with begin and end updates.
    });
});
```

******EDIT*****
Lets try this

```
@synchronized (self) {
    // your deletion code with begin and end updates for the table. Throw away the dispatch code, go back to the old code with Begin and end updates and apply lock. like this.
}
```

Comment: I get it, when multiple data is getting deleted at the same time, your method deletes multiple data from the array while animation is going on for a table cell delete. Hence the problem. guess you will have to go with the serialized queue.

Comment: still same problem :(
I remove data from datas in the first dispatch and in the second one I call the cell deletion surrounded by beingUpdates and endUpdates

Comment: i have changed the first dispatch to run on sync ..try that.

Comment: I guess UI update should be executed once the queue is empty and before something get in the queue

Comment: yes ..you will need to make it so that at a Time one item is deleted from array and one cell, until cell deletion is completed, we do not delete another item from the array. I think we should apply a lock and see .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61106/discussion-between-titmael-and-croyneaus4u).